# Bamboo Trimming Problem - Finding a recurring sequence

Tags: algorithms

Suppose you have *n* bamboo tree's each with different growth rates. At the end of the day you may only cut one bamboo back down to size 0.

What is the best way to find a periodic schedule such that the height of the tallest bamboo tree is minimized.

I have several growth rates but the one I'm most interested in is [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21] - which is the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've inputted these growth rates into excel as a row, then along the left column the number of days (up to 50, but doesn't matter). Then I colour in each cell where I decide to cut the bamboo and note its height.

Comment: I'm also stuck on the Fibonacci one, managed to get it down to 84. Any other method results in the tree with gr 5 and the tree with gr8 fighting for a place when I cut any other tree because 13 and 21 have to be cut every 4 and 2 days otherwise youre already on a crazy number.